# JMeter - error in Load WSDL

Tags: jmeter

I was trying to test webservice on jmeter and I am using WebService(SOAP)
Request (DEPRECIATED) in Thread Group>add>sampler>WebService(SOAP)
Request (DEPRECIATED) and getting this error. I already use the WSDL URL in browser and it recognized, but why in jmeter wasn't? I am using Apache JMeter (2.9 r1437961)

[image: fail to get access]

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgrade your JMeter to the latest version (2.13 as for now), it's available from the [Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page
2. Don't use WebService(SOAP) Request, switch to [SOAP/XML-RPC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request) instead. You can even use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, but if you need to send SOAPAction - you'll need to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to send headers like SOAPAction and Content-Type
3. Response code 401 means "Unauthorized", it looks like your web service needs some credentials. Add [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to your test plan and supply credentials there.